# How to get $config['imgURL_Path'] value from CodeIgniter's file config.php NOT from CI controller?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to get some constants, defined in CodeIgnitor in /application/config/config.php, but when i am outside CI controller. For example, i have a file that generates image thumbs or something else, that is outside CodeIgniter mvc framework. Cause the file /application/config/config.php has a string:

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

i can't just do something like :

```
include '/application/config/config.php';
$imgPath = $config['imgURL_Path'];
```

I tried to add this strings, but no result:

```
if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.'/';
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

define('BASEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $system_path));
include '/application/config/config.php';
$imgPath = $config['imgURL_Path'];
```

i also tried to make a file ci.php with this content:

```
<?php
// file: ci.php
ob_start();
require_once '../index.php'; 
ob_get_clean();
return $CI;
?>
```

and use it like:

```
$CI = require_once 'ci.php';
$imgPath = $CI->config->item('imgURL_Path');
```

but also no luck. What can be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an URL_path or a variable that can be accessed anywhere, you can use helper.

1 Create a file in folder `helpers`, let's say you named it `myvariable_helper.php` //**make sure you add '_helper' before the .php**.

2 Open `autoload` in config folder, then search for `$autoload['helper']`
, insert your newly created helper there like this: `$autoload['helper'] = array(url, myvariable)`

3 Save the autoload, then open `myvariable_helper.php`, and add a function. Let's say you add an URL to a function like this:

```
<?php

function img_path()
{
    $imgURL_Path = 'www.your_domain.com/image/upload';
    return $imgURL_Path;
}
```

4 Call the function anywhere (even outside your MVC folder), using the function name, for example:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['url'] = img_path(); //assign the variable using return value (which is 'www.your_domain.com/image/upload')

    $this->load->view('Your_View', $data); //just for example
}
```

Note:
This helper can't be accessed from browser (like your model folder), so it's safe

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i can't use this in my image thumbs generator. The generator file is situated in /generator folder in the root of my website, it contents:
`
<?php
$imgPath = img_path();
// some code generating thumb
?>
`
and of cource it shows error "undefined function img_path()" when i try to use the generator in my site, while inserting images with `<img src="/generator/index.php?image=somephotourl.jpg">`
What can i do in this situation?

Comment: @NatalyaGNS sorry I delete my previous comment after re-reading your question and comment, I need to ask for clarity.
1. is this generator is part of your project?
2. what is the content of $config['imgURL_Path']?
3. what is the correlation between this code `<img src="/generator/index.php?image=somephotourl.jpg">`  and `<?php $imgPath = img_path()` ?

Comment: The generator is a part of my site, but not a part of codeignitor's mvc structure. The content of $config['imgURL_Path'] is url where images are situated. So, the generator takes image file name as a GET parameter and generates resized image : /generator/index.php?image=somephotourl.jpg. The full adress to somephotourl.jpg is `$config['imgURL_Path'].'/somephotourl.jpg`, the variable `$imgPath = $config['imgURL_Path']` is in generator's index.php. So, finally i just duplicate $config['imgURL_Path'] in generator's index.php, the same as it is in config.php: `$config['imgURL_Path'] = "someurl";`

Comment: yes, accessing other project config is not good in CI. Either you copy the code into your project, or create a controller in that project that act as API and return the img path or any type of content as a response.